# How to calculate the distance between $m$ points evenly distributed on the surface of the n-1-sphere according to the radius $r$?

Tags: geometry, homology-sphere

There is an n-1-sphere defined by $S^{n-1}=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n: \|\mathbf{x}\|=r\}$ ($r>0$ is the radius here). If n=2, it is the edge of a circle; If n=3, it is the surface of a sphere.
There are $m$ points on the n-1-sphere.
If we let the distance $d$ between the two points with the smallest distance be maximized. In this way, are these $m$ points uniformly distributed in the space? Whether the distance $d$ can be expressed as a function of $r$?

Comment: $d$ as function of $r$ is very simple $d(r)=a_{m,n} r$. The main hardness is determining $a_{m,n}$. At $n=2$: $a_{m,2}=2\sin\frac{\pi}{m}$.

Comment: Yes, it is very simple when $n=2$. But for high-dimensional data, how to deduce a $d (r)$?

Comment: $d(r)=kr$ for all $n,m>1$, $k$ is constant not depending on $r$

Comment: If it is difficult to determine $k$, can we infer the upper bound of $d(r)$?

Comment: For any $n$ and $m$: $d(r) \leq 2r$

Comment: This constraint is too loose, some strict version is needed in this case.

Comment: This is strict answer. For any $r$ one can find such $n$ and $m$ that $d(r)=2r$.